# Check what a value of a specifc key is in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, if-statement, dictionary

Im new to Dictionaries, so i have this basic question.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> usersLastStamp = checking.checkLastStamp();
```

How can i do a if statement that checks if a value of a specific key is something?

Like this:

```
if(usersLastStamp.the_value_of_key("theKey") == "someValue")
{
    //Do something
}
```

I've taken a look at TryGetValue, but im not quite sure how to use it directly like the above in a if statement.

Comment: you can google it ... How to take value from Dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`usersLastStamp["theKey"]` will throw an exception if the key is not present in the dictionary (as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx)). You can use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and combine it with [short circuit evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx):

```
string value = null;
if (usersLastStamp.TryGetValue("theKey", out value) && (value == "someValue"))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
if(usersLastStamp["theKey"] != null && usersLastStamp["theKey"] == "SomeValue")
{
      // Your cdoe writes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Folks have already answered the `TryGetValue` approach, but as an alternative: if it is an option, you *could* also consider using `StringDictionary` instead of `Dictionary<string,string>` - this returns `null` in the case that there is no value at that key, so you can just use:

```
if(usersLastStamp["theKey"] == "someValue")
```

without any risk of it erroring.

Comment: I would love feedback on that downvote; this seems an entirely reasonable approach.

Comment: I would actually love some feedback on the downvote on this too. This looks more readable compared to the TryGetValue approuch IMO.

Comment: @DanielJørgensen I think it is actually just someone being upset when I pointed out some major problems in their now-deleted answer. I suspect I'll survive just fine ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```
string someVal = "";

if (myDict.ContainsKey(someKey))
 someVal = myDict[someKey];
```

or

```
string someVal = "";
if (myDict.TryGetValue(somekey, out someVal))
```

and then your if:

```
if (someVal == "someValue")
```

TryGetValue takes an out parameter, returns a bool, retruns true and updates the parameter if the key exists in the dictionary, if key doesn't exist in the dictionary returns false. Or you have to check if the key exists in the dictionary and only if it exists then take the value from it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ContainsKey?